# var toAdd = $('input[name=checkListItem]').val(); what does this code do?

Tags: jquery

I just understand the declaration of `toAdd` and what `.val();` does, but can someone explain what `$('input[name=checkListItem]')` means?

Answer (score 1):

`$('input[name=checkListItem]')` will select all the `input` elements having attribute `name` as **checkListItem**

If there are multiple `input` element of the same name, it'll return the list of all the elements.

> Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value exactly equal to a certain value.

Docs: https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Comment: @AmmarCSE Right! Updated.